# Python `if x is not None` or `if not x is None`?

Tags: python, nonetype, boolean-expression, pep8

I've always thought of the `if not x is None` version to be more clear, but Google's [style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html?showone=True/False_evaluations#True/False_evaluations) and [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations) both use `if x is not None`. Are there any minor performance differences (I'm assuming not), and is there any case where one really doesn't fit (making the other a clear winner for my convention)?*

*I'm referring to any singleton, rather than just `None`.

> ...to compare singletons like
> None. Use is  or is not.

Comment: `is not` is an operator in it's own right. Like `!=`. If you prefer `not x is None` then your should also prefer `not a == b` over `a != b`.

Comment: @TomaszGandor I no longer have this opinion about `not x is None` (the answers here convinced me) - it is, however, worth noting that `not a == b` is the preferred style in Python, compared to `a != b`.

Comment: @orokusaki is `not a == b` really the preferred style? I have never seen it done that way and everywhere I look people all use `!=`.

Comment: @orokusaki In Python readability counts so it is a preferred style to use one operator `!=` instead of two operators `not`, `==`.

Comment: PEP8 [explicitly specifies](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations) that the former (`if foo is not None`) is “correct”, while the latter is “wrong”.

Answer (score 1295, accepted):

There's no performance difference, as they compile to the same bytecode:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis("not x is None")
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (x)
              2 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              4 COMPARE_OP               9 (is not)
              6 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis("x is not None")
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (x)
              2 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              4 COMPARE_OP               9 (is not)
              6 RETURN_VALUE
```

Stylistically, I try to avoid `not x is y`, a human reader might misunderstand it as `(not x) is y`. If I write `x is not y` then there is no ambiguity.

Comment: Unless the same human reader thought it was `x is (not y)`.  But I tend to agree with you for your other reasoning.

Comment: additionally "is not" is less ambiguous in this context "if a is not None and b is None:" vs "if not a is None and b is None:"

Comment: the operator should be "aint"

Comment: or "unless" (`if not x is None` -> `unless x is None`)

Comment: In the end `x != None` is the clearest syntax, no need to invent the octagonal wheel.

Comment: I think exactly the opposite is true.   The first time I saw `x is not y`  I thought the programmer was comparing x to "not y".

Comment: @mins while that's true, `==` doesn't check the exact same thing as `is`. For example, `[1, 2, 3] == [1, 2, 3]` is true, but `[1, 2, 3] is [1, 2, 3]` is false. (same value vs. "are they the exact same object")

Comment: @jemand771: Correct, I'd say checking `x is None` (x is the object which value is None) is mentally wrong, as we don't care (and don't know) if `None` constant is represented by one or multiple objects, we are interested in the value only and `x == None` (x value is equal to None value) is the correct translation of what we want to do. Same for other built-in singletons, `True`, etc. This confusion doesn't exist in common languages, but in python there is no actual constants, at best singletons, a questionable choice according to pythonic verses (explicit is better than implicit).

Comment: Having two syntax options goes against one of the Zen of Python principles: "There should be one– and preferably only one –obvious way to do it". Having a space in the operator `is not` is confusing. It should be either `isnot` or `aint`

Answer (score 424):

Both Google and [Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations)'s style guide is the best practice:

```
if x is not None:
    # Do something about x
```

Using `not x` can cause unwanted results.

See below:

```
>>> x = 1
>>> not x
False
>>> x = [1]
>>> not x
False
>>> x = 0
>>> not x
True
>>> x = [0]         # You don't want to fall in this one.
>>> not x
False
```

You may be interested to see what literals are evaluated to `True` or `False` in Python:

- [Truth Value Testing](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html)

---

**Edit for comment below:**

I just did some more testing. `not x is None` doesn't negate `x` first and then compared to `None`. In fact, it seems the `is` operator has a higher precedence when used that way:

```
>>> x
[0]
>>> not x is None
True
>>> not (x is None)
True
>>> (not x) is None
False
```

Therefore, `not x is None` is just, in my honest opinion, best avoided.

---

**More edit:**

I just did *more* testing and can confirm that bukzor's comment is correct. (At least, I wasn't able to prove it otherwise.)

This means `if x is not None` has the exact result as `if not x is None`. I stand corrected. Thanks bukzor.

However, my answer still stands: **Use the conventional `if x is not None`**. `:]`

Answer (score 144):

Code should be written to be understandable to the programmer first, and the compiler or interpreter second. The "is not" construct resembles English more closely than "not is".

Comment: "*Code should be written to be understandable to the programmer first*": That was the principle used to design COBOL, a language from non academics, which received much [condescension  from academics](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~ben/papers/Schneiderman1985Relationship.pdf), some being legitimate, most not. As for the reasons... "*For a computer scientist to write sympathetically about COBOL is an act bordering on heresy. It requires courage because academic colleagues and data processing professionals are both likely to be suspicious of my motives.*"

Answer (score 44):

> ## Python `if x is not None` or `if not x is None`?

TLDR: The bytecode compiler parses them both to `x is not None` - so for readability's sake, use `if x is not None`.

### Readability

We use Python because we value things like human readability, useability, and correctness of various paradigms of programming over performance.

Python optimizes for readability, especially in this context.

### Parsing and Compiling the Bytecode

The `not` [binds more weakly](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) than `is`, so there is no logical difference here. See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#is-not):

> The operators `is` and `is not` test for object identity: `x is y` is true
>   if and only if x and y are the same object. `x is not y` yields the
>   inverse truth value.

The `is not` is specifically provided for in the Python [grammar](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/grammar.html) as a readability improvement for the language:

```
comp_op: '<'|'>'|'=='|'>='|'<='|'<>'|'!='|'in'|'not' 'in'|'is'|'is' 'not'
```

And so it is a unitary element of the grammar as well.

Of course, it is not parsed the same:

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.dump(ast.parse('x is not None').body[0].value)
"Compare(left=Name(id='x', ctx=Load()), ops=[IsNot()], comparators=[Name(id='None', ctx=Load())])"
>>> ast.dump(ast.parse('not x is None').body[0].value)
"UnaryOp(op=Not(), operand=Compare(left=Name(id='x', ctx=Load()), ops=[Is()], comparators=[Name(id='None', ctx=Load())]))"
```

But then the byte compiler will actually translate the `not ... is` to `is not`:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(lambda x, y: x is not y)
  1           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              3 LOAD_FAST                1 (y)
              6 COMPARE_OP               9 (is not)
              9 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis(lambda x, y: not x is y)
  1           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              3 LOAD_FAST                1 (y)
              6 COMPARE_OP               9 (is not)
              9 RETURN_VALUE
```

So for the sake of readability and using the language as it was intended, please use `is not`.

To not use it ***is not*** wise.

Comment: "The `not` binds more weakly than `is`, so there is no logical difference here" -- except that Python does not have to enforce logical and algebraic identities to hold (no intrinsic reason for `(1 + 2)*3` to evaluate the same as `1*3 + 2*3`).  Here apparently Python is cheating and optimising `UNARY_NOT` away.

Answer (score 34):

The answer is simpler than people are making it.

There's no technical advantage either way, and "x is not y" is what *everybody else uses*, which makes it the clear winner.  It doesn't matter that it "looks more like English" or not; everyone uses it, which means every user of Python--even Chinese users, whose language Python looks nothing like--will understand it at a glance, where the slightly less common syntax will take a couple extra brain cycles to parse.

Don't be different just for the sake of being different, at least in this field.

Answer (score 18):

Personally, I use

```
if not (x is None):
```

which is understood immediately without ambiguity by every programmer, even those not expert in the Python syntax.

Comment: A fair argument that I agree with, but I believe the argument of following idiomatic style is stronger.

Comment: +1 To most non-python programmers `if x is not None` sounds like `if x is (not None)` which is most likely a coding error. On the other hand to most python programmers `if not (x is None)` sounds like you have no experience with the language.

Answer (score 11):

The `is not` operator is preferred over negating the result of `is` for stylistic reasons. "`if x is not None:`" reads just like English, but "`if not x is None:`" requires understanding of the operator precedence and does not read like english.

If there is a performance difference my money is on `is not`, but this almost certainly isn't the motivation for the decision to prefer that technique. It would obviously be implementation-dependent. Since `is` isn't overridable, it should be easy to optimise out any distinction anyhow.

Answer (score 4):

`if not x is None` is more similar to other programming languages, but `if x is not None` definitely sounds more clear (and is more grammatically correct in English) to me.

That said it seems like it's more of a preference thing to me.

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer the more readable form `x is not y`
than I would think how to eventually write the code handling precedence of the operators in order to produce much more readable code.