# "None not in" vs "not None in"

Tags: python, syntax, logic

Unless I'm crazy `if None not in x` and `if not None in x` are equivalent. Is there a preferred version? I guess `None not in` is more english-y and therefore more pythonic, but `not None in` is more like other language syntax. Is there a preferred version?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710940

Comment: If you just change 1 operator to another operator, a lot of the questions on SO would be duplicates

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They compile to the same bytecode, so yes they are equivalent.

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(lambda: None not in x)
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (x)
              6 COMPARE_OP               7 (not in)
              9 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis(lambda: not None in x)
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (x)
              6 COMPARE_OP               7 (not in)
              9 RETURN_VALUE
```

The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#notin) also makes it clear that the two are equivalent:

> `x not in s` returns the negation of `x in s`.

As you mention `None not in x` is more natural English so I prefer to use this.

If you write `not y in x` it might be unclear whether you meant `not (y in x)` or `(not y) in x`. There is no ambiguity if you use `not in`.

Comment: thanks, didn't know you could compare the bytecode like this.

Answer (score 7):

The expression

```
not (None in x)
```

(parens added for clarity) is an ordinary boolean negation. However,

```
None not in x
```

is special syntax added for more readable code (there's no possibility here, nor does it make sense, to use and, or, etc in front of the in). If this special case was added, use it.

Same applies to

```
foo is not None
```

vs.

```
not foo is None
```

I find the "is not" much clearer to read. As an additional bonus, if the expression is part of a larger boolean expression, the scope of the not is immediately clear.