# "x not in y" or "not x in y"

Tags: python, syntax, operators

When testing for membership, we can use:

```
x not in y
```

Or alternatively:

```
not x in y
```

There can be many possible contexts for this expression depending on `x` and `y`.  It could be for a substring check, list membership, dict key existence, for example.

- Are the two forms always equivalent?
- Is there a preferred syntax?

Answer (score 129, accepted):

They always give the same result.

In fact, `not 'ham' in 'spam and eggs'` appears to be special cased to perform a single "not in" operation, rather than an "in" operation and then negating the result:

```
>>> import dis

>>> def notin():
    'ham' not in 'spam and eggs'
>>> dis.dis(notin)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('ham')
              3 LOAD_CONST               2 ('spam and eggs')
              6 COMPARE_OP               7 (not in)
              9 POP_TOP             
             10 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             13 RETURN_VALUE    

>>> def not_in():
    not 'ham' in 'spam and eggs'
>>> dis.dis(not_in)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('ham')
              3 LOAD_CONST               2 ('spam and eggs')
              6 COMPARE_OP               7 (not in)
              9 POP_TOP             
             10 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             13 RETURN_VALUE    

>>> def not__in():
    not ('ham' in 'spam and eggs')
>>> dis.dis(not__in)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('ham')
              3 LOAD_CONST               2 ('spam and eggs')
              6 COMPARE_OP               7 (not in)
              9 POP_TOP             
             10 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             13 RETURN_VALUE        

>>> def noteq():
    not 'ham' == 'spam and eggs'
>>> dis.dis(noteq)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('ham')
              3 LOAD_CONST               2 ('spam and eggs')
              6 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
              9 UNARY_NOT           
             10 POP_TOP             
             11 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             14 RETURN_VALUE
```

I had thought at first that they always gave the same result, but that `not` on its own was simply a low precedence logical negation operator, which could be applied to `a in b` just as easily as any other boolean expression, whereas `not in` was a separate operator for convenience and clarity.

The disassembly above was revealing! It seems that while `not` obviously is a logical negation operator, the form `not a in b` is special cased so that it's not actually using the general operator. This makes `not a in b` literally the same expression as `a not in b`, rather than merely an expression that results in the same value.

Comment: Keep in mind that this is only an implementation detail. I can't even find a mention of `not x in xs` in the docs.

Comment: @phant0m Absolutely; the way you're supposed to think of `not x in xs` is `not (x in xs)`. But the fact that it's implemented by parsing it into precisely the same bytecode as `x not in xs` very clearly shows that they must be always identical, as opposed to things like `not x == y` vs `x != y` which *should* give the same result, but don't have to (depending on the implementations of `__eq__` and `__ne__` involved).

Comment: You've run into a [CPython peephole optimisation](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ed8b0ee1c531/Python/peephole.c#l405); a compile-time optimisation that other Python implementations such as Jython and IronPython are free to ignore or copy (it is not part of the language specification).

Answer (score 23):

1. No, there is no difference.

> The operator `not in` is defined to have the inverse true value of `in`.
>
> —[Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#notin)
>
> I would assume `not in` is preferred because it is more obvious and they added a special case for it.

Answer (score 11):

They are identical in meaning, but the [pycodestyle Python style guide checker (formerly called pep8)](https://pypi.org/project/pycodestyle/) prefers the `not in` operator in [rule E713](https://pycodestyle.pycqa.org/en/latest/intro.html#error-codes):

> E713:     test for membership should be `not in`

See also ["Python `if x is not None` or `if not x is None`?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710940/python-if-x-is-not-none-or-if-not-x-is-none) for a very similar choice of style.

Answer (score 2):

Others have already made it very clear that the two statements are, down to a quite low level, equivalent.

However, I don't think that anyone yet has stressed enough that since this leaves the choice up to you, you should

### **choose the form that makes your code as readable as possible.**

And not necessarily as readable as possible *to anyone*, even if that's of course a nice thing to aim for. No, make sure the code is as readable as possible *to you*, since you are the one who is the most likely to come back to this code later and try to read it.

Comment: If you're working in a large team or on code that is likely to be untouched for a while, it may be more likely that someone else has to maintain it.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, there is no difference. And there is no preference.

Answer (score 0):

Syntactically they're the same statement.  I would be quick to state that `'ham' not in 'spam and eggs'` conveys clearer intent, but I've seen code and scenarios in which `not 'ham' in 'spam and eggs'` conveys a clearer meaning than the other.