# My function remove_stopwords. Removes every stopwords in a word

Tags: python, nltk

So im trying to remove all the stop-words from a text file. The problem is, it is removing the stopwords each in every word.

```
def remove_stopwords(input):
    stop_words  = set(stopwords.words('english'))
    filtered_words = [word for word in input if not word in stop_words]
    return filtered_words

Sample Input: Damage from Typhoon Lando soars to P6B
Output: Dge fr Tphn Ln r  P6B
```

Comment: If `input` is a string... you need to break it up into words... eg: `[word for word in input.split() if word not in stop_words]`, then do what you want with the resultant list... otherwise you're iterating over each character and removing that where that character exists in the stop words.

Comment: @JonClements thank you sir!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tokenize your `str` input before removing stop words.

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk import word_tokenize

stoplist  = set(stopwords.words('english'))

def remove_stopwords(text):
    return [word for word in word_tokenize(text) if not word in stoplist]
```

Comment: Just to note `not word in` vs `word not in`... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8738388/order-of-syntax-for-using-not-and-in-keywords (`not in` is generally considered to be clearer as it's closer to English - although there's no real technical difference)

Comment: I've changed the `not word in` -> `word not in`. Then again, I thought maybe this would be great to point people to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8738388/order-of-syntax-for-using-not-and-in-keywords and so I changed it back to `not word in`. Thanks @JonClements for pointing this out ;P