# Does `not x in y` follow the operator precedence rules?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The [canonical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8738388/x-not-in-y-or-not-x-in-y?noredirect=1&lq=1) on the difference between `not x in y` and `x not in y` states that these two are equivalent in implementation (in CPython). The [operator precedence rules](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) state that the Boolean `not` has higher precedence than `in`. So shouldn't `not x in y` be implemented to be equivalent to `(not x) in y`?

Consider

```
x = False
list2 = ['a']
not x in list2
Out[19]: True
(not x) in list2
Out[20]: False
```

I would have expected second last statement to be `False`, if I'm understanding the precedence rules correctly.

Comment: The answer to your question is in the question you linked. Last paragraph of the accepted answer: "the form `not a in b` is special cased so that it's not actually using the general operator.  This makes `not a in b` literally the same expression as `a not in b`"

Comment: Also you have read the table wrong, it lists operators from **least to most** order of precedence, therefore `not x in y` is the same as `not (x in y)` and not `(not x) in y` as you claim. Whew, too many nots in that sentence

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather subtle but if you look in the official documentation that you linked to, you will see that "not in" is its own operator, which has a higher precedence than "not"  and the same precedence as "in".

Your mistake is probably coming from reading the operator precedence rules the wrong way around. As it currently stands, the **lowest** precedence comes higher up in the list.
So `not x in list2` is equvalent to `not (x in list2)`.

Your last assumption will, because you have surrounded it with parentheses, first evaluate `not x` to a boolean (False), then check if that boolean is in the list (which it is not, there's only a string in the list), and return False.