# Effect of the position of 'not' in python statement on performance

Tags: python, list, boolean-operations

In the application I am currently developing in python3, I often use statements like

```
elem_in_list = elem in list
```

But sometimes I need to check whether the element is not in the list.
Is there a performance differece between

```
elem_not_in_list = not elem in list
```

and

```
elem_not_in_list = elem not in list
```

or is it just the same? Is one of the notations preferable?

Comment: Why not `timeit` and find out?

Comment: Very closely related, but not quite identical: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710940/python-if-x-is-not-none-or-if-not-x-is-none. I'm not sure whether there's an existing question for `not in`; these little words are hard to search for.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

These expressions compile to the exact same bytecode, so they're exactly equally efficient. `not in` tends to be more readable, but it's a matter of opinion.

```
>>> import dis
>>> def f(x, y):
...     return not x in y
...
>>> def g(x, y):
...     return x not in y
...
>>> dis.dis(f)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              3 LOAD_FAST                1 (y)
              6 COMPARE_OP               7 (not in)
              9 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis(g)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              3 LOAD_FAST                1 (y)
              6 COMPARE_OP               7 (not in)
              9 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: Thanks. I did not know about `dis`. This seems very useful.