# Is there a python built-in function to get 0 for None

Tags: python, integer

Is there a built-in function in python which does the following:

```
def none_safe(int_value):
    return int_value if int_value is not None else 0
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python \`if x is not None\` or \`if not x is None\`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710940/python-if-x-is-not-none-or-if-not-x-is-none)

Comment: It's not a duplicate of that, at all.

Comment: You have a typo in your post which @UriAgassi has decided to fix without knowing if it was broken or not, could you please check that the code as edited is what you actually have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the only possible inputs are `None` and instances of `int`:

```
int_value or 0
```

Some APIS, such as `dict.get`, have an argument where you can pass the default. In this case it's just a value, but note that `or` is evaluated lazily whereas a function argument is necessarily evaluated eagerly.

Other APIs, such as the constructor of `collections.defaultdict`, take a *factory* to construct defaults, i.e. you would have to pass `lambda: 0` (or just `int` since that is also a callable that returns `0`), which avoids the eagerness if that's a problem, as well as the possibility of other falsy elements.

Answer (score 1):

Even safer (usually) is to just return 0 for any value that can't be an `int`

```
def none_safe(int_value):
    try:
        return int(int_value)
    except (TypeError, ValueError):
        return 0
```

Other variations might use `isinstance` or similar depending on your exact requirements

Comment: `except` without an `Exception` is too broad for general usage. It can catch anything, even Control-C! I think that `except (TypeError, ValueError):` would be appropriate here.