# which way of checking item in list is correct

Tags: python, list, if-statement

which way of checking item in list is correct?

```
>>> lst1 = ['A', 'B']
>>> if 'C' not in lst1: print 'Hi'
...
Hi
```

or

```
>>> if not 'C' in lst1: print 'Hi'
...
Hi
```

to me the first one looks correct but still in doubt ?
not sure if this has been asked by someone on SO before if so please link

Comment: Either one works. Subjectively I prefer `if 'c' not in lst` because I find it more human readable

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python \`if x is not None\` or \`if not x is None\`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710940/python-if-x-is-not-none-or-if-not-x-is-none)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are equally correct for this case.

In the more general case such as when calling a function which returns a boolean, the `not` must go in front, so if that is easier for you to remember, you could stick with that to be consistent.

Answer (score 1):

The latter works, but some would consider it poor form or "less Pythonic". The former is more readable, and Python prides itself on being a highly readable language.

> Readability counts.

— Tim Peters, [The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)